# Check whether a key exists in memcached ( spymemchaced - Java memcached client)

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I wanna perform a code which has pseudo-code like this:

```
MemcachedClient c = new MemcachedClient(....)
if c.get("key") exists 
  print(c.get("key"))
else 
  c.add("key",expTime, value)
```

The problem is: how can I check whether `c.get("key")` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [get(String key)](http://dustin.sallings.org/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method returns null if there is no key associated with the key.

Therefore, you can get the value, and check if it is null to know if it "exists":

```
Object myObject = c.get("key");
if(c == null) { // the object does not exist
    // add the value
} else {
    System.out.println(myObject);
}
```